# Urn has theta black balls, N - theta white balls. Sample of n balls, let Y denote # black balls in n. Show (N|n)Y is MOME of theta.

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

> An urn has $\theta$ black balls, $N - \theta$ white balls. Taking a sample of $n$ balls, let $Y$ denote the number of black balls in $n$. Show that $(N|n)Y$ is MOME of $\theta$.

First I am confused on the notation. $(N|n)Y$, is that saying $N$ given $n$?

Then, I know we need to find the $k$th raw moment and set it equal to the $k$th sample moment. But I am not even sure where to start with this example.

Comment: So I figured out that (N|n)Y is hypergeometric, so the mean is nr/N. So then we set that equal to ybar and solve for r? And that is the estimator for theta?

Comment: if I do that then I get theta/N = Ybar, so theta = theta/N

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that this is a hypergeometric problem. And in your
comments you have made some progress, but with a little misunderstanding.
Perhaps a careful analysis of population vs. sample will help.

*Population:* There $N$ balls in an urn, of which $\theta$ are black. 
Thus the proportion of black balls in the urn is $\theta/N.$

*Sample:* You withdraw $n$ balls, of which $Y$ happen to be black.
Thus the proportion of black balls in your sample is $Y/n.$

The principle of 'method of moments' (MOM) estimation is to set
population mean equal to sample mean and solve for the unknown
parameter. The trick here is that these 'means' are called proportions
in this hypergeometric problem.

Thus you have $Y/n = \tilde\theta/N$. Solving, we see that the MOME is
$\tilde\theta = (N/n)Y.$

I believe you mistook a fraction bar for a vertical bar. The confusion
can be easy if italics type is not set carefully. So there is no
conditioning involved in the statement of the question.